Why do Dedekind cuts have no maximum?
There is a property of Dedekind cuts that states that there exists no maximum $a_0\in A$ for all cuts $A\in\mathbb{R}$.
My question is: Why do Dedekind cuts need this property?
What would happen if Dedekind cuts didn’t have this property?
With these questions I aim to better understand the motivation behind the definition of Dedekind cuts and the construction of $\mathbb{R}$.

What would be the maximum of a Dedekind cut that represents $\sqrt{2}$? Or are you asking about why we require this even for Dedekind cuts that ultimately represent rationals?

Doesn’t it exist because a Dedekind cut doesn’t have a maximum?

@Ian: The latter, I suspect, but we'll see.

O sorry, the site only showed me the first half of the comment, but I am indeed also asking for the latter.

One could define a Dedekind cut differently, so as to use partitions of the rationals $\mathbb Q$ as a disjoint union $A\cup B$ where instead of $A$ never having a maximum we instead have $B$ (every element of which exceeds every element of $A$) never having a minimum.  Citing the textbook or other source where you found the Dedekind cut construction would improve your Question.

It's a minor technicality that makes the reasoning easier. You could allow Dedekind cuts that include their maximal element if their supremum happens to be rational. To get things to work out in proving the properties you want the cuts to satisfy, you'd have to insist that a cut with a rational supremum included that supremum (to ensure uniqueness) and you'd get lots of special cases to deal with in the definitions of the arithmetic operations. It's simpler to work with cuts that always exclude their supremum even if it's rational.

The informal idea behind a Dedekind cut is that each real number is identified with the set of rationals that come before it. With this notion in mind, there are two candidates for how we should define the real number corresponding to a rational number $q$: it should either be $\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x<q\}$ or $\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x\le q\}$. Insisting that Dedekind cuts have no maximum eliminates this ambiguity.
Ultimately, though, it is best not to get too invested in how the set of real numbers is precisely constructed. What matters is that they can be constructed, i.e. that we can prove the existence of a complete ordered field (and show that it is unique in a suitable sense). Once we have completed the construction, we can mentally discard any of the "implementation details" that it involved, and focus solely on the axiomatic properties of $\mathbb R$ – these are what really matter 99.9% of the time.

I suspect it's because it's easier this way.
Multiplication is a bit complicated with Dedekind cuts, but I think you can imagine that if we square $\sqrt{2}$ according to Dedekind cut arithmetic, you'll end up with a cut $(A, B)$ with $2 \in B$, not $A$.
On the other hand, I think there is a way to make it work the other way, but it's less intuitive in some way.
Leaving this as community wiki, because I'd like others to correct/add to this as appropriate.

I don't think there is any intrinsic way the construction works better with $A$ having no greatest element than with $B=A^c$ having no least element.  What is necessary is to pick one alternative or the other so that the representation of a real number in terms of a Dedekind cut will be unique.

@hardmath: I'm sure it's not intrinsic. I should've made clearer that I was simply speculating as to whether there was a pedagogical advantage. Whatever it is, it must surely be fairly slight.

Informally, a Dedekind cut represents the number that is the cuts supremum if the supremum exists (for instance, $(-\infty,2)$ represents $2$). And the cut represents the number that should be its supremum if the supremum doesn't exist (for instance, $\sqrt2$ should be the supremum of $\{x\in\mathbb Q|x<0~\mathrm{ or }~x^2<2\}$, and the cut represents that number).
Now imagine what would happen if Dedekind cuts would lack the axiom that they have no maximum: $(-\infty,2)$ and $(-\infty,2]$ would both be Dedekind cuts. But they'd represent the same number, namely 2! So we'd have different Dedekind cuts representing the same number, and thus no one-to-one correspondence between real numbers and cuts.
So we have to decide wether Dedekind cuts should include a maximum or not. And since some of them can't have a maximum because not even their supremum exists yet, we should exclude cuts containing a maximum.
